# SQL Server system procedure 'sp_replmonitorrefreshjob'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What does this procedure do? It's a little discussed SP with no MSDN reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the procedure, then click "Modify" (obviously you don't want to execute against it, so I would disconnect the query window). That is the most definative way I know of to figure out what a system stored procedure does. Whether you will find official documentation on it, probably not. From what I [understand](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/measuringtransactionalreplicationlatencywithouttracertokens) it is basically just refreshing the monitor data.